# ListView binding in WPF not showing expected collection items

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Why isn't this binding working?

```
<Window x:Class="S3PackageInstaller.MainWindow" x:Name="Window1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s3u="clr-namespace:S3PackageInstaller"
    Icon="App.ico" Title="Sims 3 Package Installer" Height="480" Width="740">

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="True"
            Margin="20,20,0,20">

            <!-- this is the binding that isn't working -->
            <ListView Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window1, Path=InstalledPackages}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Installed Packages" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Filename}"></GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>                
            </ListView>

    <!-- snip -->

</Window>
```

Relevant code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> InstalledPackages { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InstalledPackages = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        LoadInstalledPackages();
    }

    private void LoadInstalledPackages()
    {
        var installPath = Settings.Default.TargetDirectory;
        var packages = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(installPath, "*.package");

        InstalledPackages.Clear();
        foreach (string filename in packages)
            InstalledPackages.Add(new { Filename = filename });
    }

    // snip...
}
```

When I run the program, the ListView is empty. When debugging, I have verified that the collection contains items after LoadInstalledPackages is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that while your collection property is an `ObservableCollection`, so will notify of collection changes, the property itself does not raise a change notification when you first assign to it. When you create your window as follows:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InstalledPackages = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    LoadInstalledPackages();
}
```

When `InitializeComponent` is invoked your UI is created and bindings constructed. At this point `InstalledPackages`  is null. In the next line you create your collection, but because `InstalledPackages` does not raise a `PropertyChanged` event, your binding is not updated.

Either implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or assign the  `ObservableCollection` to this property before invoking `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: Hmmm.. I SWEAR I tried that earlier, but doing so now fixed it, so, cheers!